# JMS with Spring Integration or Spring Batch

Tags: jms, spring-integration, spring-batch

Our project is to integrate two applications, using the REST API of each and using JMS (to provide asynchronous nature). Application-1 writes the message on the queue. The next step is to read the message from the queue, process it, and send it to application2.

I have two questions:

1. Should we use one more queue for storing messages after processing and before sending them to application2?
2. Should we use spring batch or spring integration to read/process the data?

Answer (score 0):

Or you don't show the whole premise, or you really try to overhead your app. If there is just need to read messages from the queue, there is just enough to use Spring JMS directly... From other side with the Spring Integration and its Adapters power you can just process messes from the `<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter>` to the `<int-http:outbound-channel-adapter>`.

Don't see reason to store message somewhere else in the reading and sending process. Just because with some exception here you just rollback your message to the JMS queue back.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Artem. The thing is our team is new to this framework and just want to go with the best suitable one. We can move ahead with one queue. Thanks!! We also have one more doubt here, we want to have multiple producers for the queue and multiple readers. as one message write/read will slow down the process. How to incorporate multithreading with spring JMS or spring integration? Please suggest.